# Embed doxygen docu in powershell script

Tags: powershell, doxygen

I want to make a PowerShell module or script with a nice documentation. The PowerShell documents are written to a comment block like this:

```
<#   
    .SYNOPSIS
    My module does a nice job.
    .DESCRIPTION
    The author has written a lot of code than you can enjoy.
    .PARAMETER
    Yes, we got parameters.
    .EXAMPLE
    Here we are: call it.
#>
```

The documentation can be read with the PowerShell get-help cmdlet.

Now I want to generate a doxygen documentation. In the hope that doxygen parses this similar like a C file I changed the comment and added some tags:

```
<##
    @overview
    .SYNOPSIS
    My module does a nice job.
    @version 08.15
#>
```

Further I changed the Doxyfile:

```
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.psm1
```

So doxygen reads this file:

> Parsing files
> Reading D:/Projects/Tools/Scripts/MakeDelivery/MakeDelivery.psm1...
> Building group list...

The PowerShell file appears in the File List of the generated HTML documentation but has no text at all. What is necessary to use doxygen to create a documentation that is readable outside the PowerShell?
The documentation that is available should be used as much as possible.

Comment: I don't think this will as powerscript documentation and commands are not recognized by doxygen, you first have to transfer it to something understood by doxygen, see ...FILTER.., in the Doxyfile. This transfer has probably to be done for the code and the comment.

Comment: Forgot to mention the setting of `EXTENSION_MAPPING` in my previous comment.